# Tomcat Log Remote Access

Tags: java, tomcat, logging

I'm able access the manager webapp of my tomcat server hosted back home. I'm able to deploy and undeploy webapps and test them. But I wanted to know, if there is a way to access the tomcat logs **remotely** in case of a error on the remote server.

Comment: Yes. Log in via SSH, and view them... I'm against using the manager webapp on web-facing servers - that's the first thing I clean out from them. One less thing to worry about. And you can always do anything in command line...

Comment: Thanks, I'll keep in mind and remove it once i'm done with the development. But at the moment, only me and tomcat know about it :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logback logging library (Log4j successor) has a module for that:
http://logback.qos.ch/access.html